# What is the best way to represent an environment state in my case?

Tags: machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, reinforcement-learning

I'm trying to make a reinforcement learning model that plays a simple 1v1 platformer game as one of the players. There are two players represented by rectangles that can shoot each other with rectangle bullets in this game. So the number of bullets is a countable set because players can spawn them as many as they want.

How to represent state in this kind of game? Of course, I need to have something like [p1x, p1y, p1velX, p1velY, p2x, p2y, p2velX, p2velY] (p1x is player one X coordinate, p2velY is player 2 velocity)  but there are bullets in this game so the shape of a state vector can be arbitrary like [p1x, p1y, p1velX, p1velY, p2x, p2y, p2velX, p2velY, b1x, b1y, b1velX, b1velY, b2x, b2y, b2velX, b2velY ...] where "b1x" stands for "bullet number 1 x coordinate" and so on. And I think that a vector with an arbitrary shape cannot fit into a neural network. So how should I really represent the  state?

[image]

Here you can see a screenshot of the game, players are the red rectangles and bullets are the gray rectangles. Player 1 is currently jumping and the bullets are moving right

Answer (score 0):

If you use OpenAI Gym to create your environment, you have to set the low_obs and high_obs and use the function "Box" to create your observation_space. Something like that :

```
n = 10 # the number of parameters in your state
low_obs=np.array([0.0]*n) # we assume [0,0,0,...] are the min values
low_obs=np.array([10.0]*n) # the max values
```

So, your observation space can be :

```
self.observation_space = Box(low_obs, high=high_obs ,dtype=np.float32)
```